# можно ли на php спарсить reviews от google

Tags: php, парсер

Задача, вытащить reviews компаний, на подобии этой: [google reviews](https://www.google.com/maps/place/WallyPark+Lot+2+-+San+Diego/@32.7364829,-117.1790342,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!1m6!3m5!1s0x80d95359e64b6783:0x421b4f760bd4ac87!2sFLUXX+Nightclub!8m2!3d32.71071!4d-117.161346!3m6!1s0x80deab347b58f853:0xde16bc76d7bb01c3!8m2!3d32.7364786!4d-117.1768458!9m1!1b1)
Есть ли библиотеки позволяющие спарсить на php?
Я понимаю что здесь для подгрузки контента используется ajax. 
Для начала я написал на python3 парсер на selenium с имитацией браузера, но требования изменились и теперь желателен php который не будет требовать браузер.

Comment: что у Вас не получается?

Comment: Без браузера никак. Сервер не увидит конечную генерацию `javascript`.

Comment: А API не подходит? https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data